# Attempted relative import in non package python

Tags: python

My current directory structure

```
prem
.
├── __init__.py
├── test1.py
├── test2.py
```

test1.py

```
print 'test1.py'
```

test2.py

```
import  sys
sys.path.append('/opt/sw/p3/src/prem')
print sys.path
from . import test1
```

Error

```
    from . import test1
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

When I display the path , I see this directory - /opt/sw/p3/src/prem

Comment: Maybe just `import test1`?

Comment: import test1 works fine..but Im wondering why the relative import does not work

Comment: What are you doing to get that error?  Are you running `test2.py` directly?  If so, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: Im running with -m option and still same issue

Comment: @user1050619: Please edit your question to include the precise command line you are using to run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `test2.py` directly, then `prem` is already the working directory.

calling `from .` is equivalent to calling the `from prem` however if `prem` is already your working directory, it will now attempt to find another package `prem` inside the current package

try this layout:

```
/my_program
    /prem
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test1.py
    ├── test2.py
    main_test.py
```

main_test.py

```
import prem.test2
```

In this case, your working directory is now the one containing `prem`,`my_program`...   meaning that the import in `test2.py`, will work because it **will** find the `prem` package within `my_program`